# Next number in the sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Find the next three numbers of the number series :

> 0,0,3,20,115,?,?

And please also tell the series this series is following

Comment: Seemed to be a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319159/i-need-to-figure-out-a-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> 0, 0, 3, 20, 115, 714, 5033, 40312, 362871, ....

Because:

> n! - n
>  http://oeis.org/A005096

**EDIT** Seems to be a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319159/i-need-to-figure-out-a-pattern)